# Selenium and Python selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to crawl resumes on Indeed using the following repository https://github.com/GowthamGottimukkala/Indeed-resume-scraper

After fixing a few issues, I'm now trying to scrape using python puf.py, but am running into issues with selenium

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/button"}
```

Confirmed that my chromedriver was up to date and accurate for the browser I'm using. Any suggestions on how to resolve?

Comment: Hi, in general the element is hidden or cant be selected, could you include the URL so others could have a look and help

Comment: For sure, here would be the URL I was searching for beforehand https://resumes.indeed.com/

Comment: Hi, could you change that line to `//button[contains(.,'Find resumes')][1]`

Comment: It solved it by doing the following: '//button[contains(.,"Find resumes")][1]', but now having issues navigating the next section as before I had the following setup:         element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[1]/a'))
        )

Comment: what is the error then, you should read the code and understand what it is doing, as just one file and relatively short,

Comment: Error received is :File "puf.py", line 38, in <module>
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[1]/a')) and selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "puf.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(len(pages))
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: Could you change it to `//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/span/a`